# Get File Name used while exporting Printer Code Template in BarTender

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii, bartender

I am trying to find if there is a way to get the file name that we mention while exporting the Printer Code Template (see below):
[Export Printer Code Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6FlS.png)

I have tried using Format.FileName to get this but this actually gets the file name of the BTW file and not the one that I am using to export. Is there another global object property/method (PCM, PCT etc.) via which I can get the file name that I need?

Any help would be highly appreciated